# Alphabet Tracing using Clip Path and Custom Paint in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-animation

**I'm trying to make an Alphabet Tracing App Logic is Almost clear**

1- I made proper path using Custom Clipper so user can only touch inside the Path
2- I made Custom Paint as child of Custom Clipper so user can draw inside it
3- But there is an issue in this logic user can draw in whole Alphabet but requirements are slightly different. I want to draw some portion first and other portion after that how can I do that any Idea ? For Reference I am Uploading an Image you can check it as well